# jacobian and hessian of products of multivariate vector valued functions, matrix-vector products and scalar-vector products

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian, hessian-matrix

I have struggle determining the jacobian and the hessian of the following functions:
$h(x) := a(x) \cdot g(x)$ and $h(x) := f(x) A g(x)$ with $a : \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f,g : \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Can somebody tell me a general approach with such composite functions? I know that you can *somehow* apply the product rule here but neither on the internet nor in my analysis 2 book I found a proof for the multivariate product rule or a general definition.
I know this is a relatively basic question. Many thanks!

Comment: The general definition is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative But sometimes it is easier to just compute all the partials seperately.

Comment: See [Product Rule for vector output functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3244485/568204). If you want to systematically learn differential calculus in several variables in a general setting, then take a look at the Loomis and Sternberg reference I mention. See also [Deriving successively $\dot{y}=f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3967610/568204) or [second order derivative of $F(t)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3285194/568204) for some examples of computing higher derivatives (though not directly for your given function).